# SqlAlchemy Outer Join Only Returns One Table

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

So when I run 
`select * from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id;` in `sqlite3` terminal

I get the data back as I want and would expect.

However, when I run this in SqlAlchemy 
`TableOneModel.query.outerjoin(TableTwoModel,TableOneModel.id == TableTwoModel.id)`

I only get `table1` information back. I don't even get empty columns from `table2`. Am I missing something silly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably using Flask-SQLAlchemy, which provides the query property as a shortcut for selecting model entities. Your query is equivalent to

```
db.session.query(TableOneModel).\
    join(TableTwoModel,TableOneModel.id == TableTwoModel.id)
```

Either explicitly query for both entities:

```
db.session.query(TableOneModel, TableTwoModel).\
    join(TableTwoModel,TableOneModel.id == TableTwoModel.id)
```

or [add the entity](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.add_entity) to your original:

```
TableOneModel.query.\
    join(TableTwoModel,TableOneModel.id == TableTwoModel.id).\
    add_entity(TableTwoModel)
```