# sqlalchemy join returns results from first table only

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

so this is my issue, I have the following tables:

```
class ClientCampaings(Base):

__tablename__ = 'client_campaign'

campaign_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
client_id = Column(VARCHAR(50))
campaign_name = Column(VARCHAR(45))
campaign_status = Column(VARCHAR(45))
campaign_type = Column(VARCHAR(45))
registration_date = Column(DATE)


class ClientKpi(Base):

__tablename__ = 'client_kpi'

kpi_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
kpi_name = Column(VARCHAR(45))
cost_conv = Column(FLOAT)
quality_score = Column(FLOAT)



class KpiAssigment(Base):

__tablename__ = 'kpi_assigment'

assigment_id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
kpi_id = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey("client_kpi.kpi_id"))
campaign_id = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey("client_campaign.campaign_id"))
assigned_by = Column(VARCHAR(45))
timestamp = Column(TIMESTAMP)

#Basic One To Many relation
client_campaign = relationship("ClientCampaings")
client_kpi = relationship("ClientKpi")
```

Them I do the following query:

```
from database.session import MySqlConnection
from database.models import KpiAssigment,ClientKpi

db = MySqlConnection(database='db_goes_here').db_session()

kpi=db.query(KpiAssigment)\
      .join(ClientKpi)\
      .filter(KpiAssigment.kpi_id==ClientKpi.kpi_id).all()
```

Which I thought was going to be something like this:

```
SELECT kpi_assigment.*,
       client_kpi.*
FROM kpi_assigment
INNER JOIN client_kpi
ON kpi_assigment.kpi_id=client_kpi.kpi_id
```

However, when I run the SqlAlchemy query I getting back only the results from the first table:

```
 {'_sa_instance_state': <sqlalchemy.orm.state.InstanceState object at 0x7fb3d0ace910>, 'kpi_id': 1, 'assigned_by': 'xxx@email.net', 'assigment_id': 2, 'campaign_id': XXXXXXXXX, 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 7, 17, 5, 8)}
```

I was looking to get an INNER JOIN and have also the data from ClientKpi table.

I read these related issues but still not finding why this isn't working

[SqlAlchemy Outer Join Only Returns One Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47166545/sqlalchemy-outer-join-only-returns-one-table)

[How to join data from two tables in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50617343/how-to-join-data-from-two-tables-in-sqlalchemy)

and I did follow their documentation

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.join

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The query

```py
kpi=db.query(KpiAssigment)\
      .join(ClientKpi)\
      .filter(KpiAssigment.kpi_id==ClientKpi.kpi_id).all()
```

will only select the `KpiAssignemnt` table; to select the corresponding  `ClientKpi`(s) include the `ClientKpi` model in the `query`:

```py
kpi=db.query(KpiAssigment, ClientKpi).join(ClientKpi)
```

The `.filter` is redundant as SQLAlchemy will use the declared foreign keys to create the `JOIN`.

If you want to loop over the child objects for each parent you can use the relationship without an explicit join:

```py
for client_kpi in some_kpi_assignment.client_kpi:
    # do something
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, when I use que query as kpi=db.query(KpiAssigment, ClientKpi).join(ClientKpi) , what I get back is the SQL query, not the result data. thanks

Comment: Yes, you can iterate over it or add `.all()` to get the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Still trying to find out if there is a better response for this, in the meantime, I did the following and got what I was looking for:

```
 query = db.query(KpiAssigment.campaign_id, 
                  ClientKpi.cost_conv,
                  ClientKpi.quality_score)\
                  .join(ClientKpi)\
                  .filter(KpiAssigment.kpi_id==ClientKpi.kpi_id)\
                  .all()
```

Which returns the resulta has a list of tuples:

```
print(query)

>>>[(1, 6.0, 2), (2, 6.0, 2)]
```